# Following brackeys tutorial and code surrounding a "Unit" not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm following a Brackeys tutorial that shows how to create turn-based combat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_1pz_ohupPs

The issue I'm facing is that my code doesn't work with a certain line of code, and I was wondering if Unity may have changed something since the tutorial came out as it is 4 years old as of now.

Heres my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public enum BattleState { START, PLAYERTURN, ENEMYTURN, WON, LOST }

public class BattleSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject playerprefab;
    public GameObject enemyprefab;

    public Transform playerbattlestation;
    public Transform enemybattlestation;

    public TMP_Text dialogueText;

    public Unit playerUnit;
    public Unit enemyUnit;
    
    public BattleState state;

    void Start()
    {
        state = BattleState.START;
        SetupBattle();
    }

    private void SetupBattle()
    {
        GameObject playerGO = Instantiate(playerprefab, playerbattlestation);
        playerUnit = playerGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

        GameObject enemyGO = Instantiate(enemyprefab, enemybattlestation);
        enemyUnit = enemyGO.GetComponent<Unit>();

        dialogueText.text = enemyUnit.unitName + " Attacked!";  // Getting an error from this line
    }
}
```

Cant find anything references to this on google and I'm not sure what a `Unit` does, let alone how to troubleshoot it.

`Error  CS1061  'Unit' does not contain a definition for 'unitName' and no accessible extension method 'unitName' accepting a first argument of type 'Unit' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\rogue\Final Fantasy (Clone)\Assets\Scripts\BattleSystem.cs 46  Active`

Comment: Please add the error message and your `Unit`-class to your post.

Comment: Also, give the timestep if you can. @HGBadger

Comment: Hard to tell tbh .. you omitted half of the code regarding the fields an types you are using there ...

Comment: Besides from what I saw at a glance is that your `enemyprefab` should rather be `Unit` instead of `GameObject` .. it ensures you can only reference according objects that actually do have that component and it also saves one `GetComponent` call as `Instantiate` will already return a `Unit` reference

Comment: Please give the Unit Script.

Comment: @HGBadger Do you have a `Unit`-class?

Answer (score 0):

`Unit` is the MonoBehaviour you probably created earlier. Check your code for that class with this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string unitName;
    public int unitLevel;

    public int damage;

    public int maxHP;
    public int currentHP;

}
```

Comment: I can't find anything about that in my code, when hovered over the Unit it says it derives from VisualScripting, which im not sure about since im don't think I added it and the Brackeys video didn't have it as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out thanks to you guys, I was trying to refrence a script that wasn't there as I had named the Unit script something else, however it didn't initially give me an error because of Unity.VisualScripting which caused it to "work."

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people